# How do you copy a linked list into another list without using recursion

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I'm studying data structures and linked lists, but I'm not getting the concept of how to make a copy of a linked list without recursion. Can someone explain this.

Comment: why do you need to copy a linked list specifically without recursion?

Comment: interviewer asked for me ..so

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode of a simple, iterative logic would be:

1. Start at the head of the original list, `origHead`.
2. Set a temporary pointer to point to the original list's head, `tempNode = origHead`.
3. If `tempNode` = `NULL`, goto step 17.
4. If `tempNode != origHead`, goto step 10.
5. Allocate memory for the copy list's head, `copyListHead`.
6. Set `copyListHead->next` to `NULL`.
7. Set a temporary pointer to point to the copy list's head, `copyListTempNode = copyListHead`.
8. `tempNode = tempNode->next`.
9. Goto step 3.
10. Allocate memory for a node `newCopyNode`.
11. Copy `tempNode->data` to `newCopyNode->data`.
12. Set `newCopyNode->next` to NULL.
13. Point `copyListTempNode->next` to `newCopyNode`.
14. `copyListTempNode = newCopyNode`.
15. `tempNode = tempNode->next`.
16. Goto step 3.
17. Stop.

Answer (score 1):

Without recursion === using iteration. P-code:

```
LinkedList *l1 = (the_head), *l2 = copy_node(l1);
for (tmp l1->next; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next, l2 = l2->next) {
    l2->next = copy_node(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**How It Works**

1. Declare two pointers: a `dst` pointer, which will be the final function result, and `next` pointer-to-pointer, which always holds the *address* of the pointer that will receive the next node allocation. The `next` pointer-to-pointer initially holds the address of `dst`.
2. While we still have nodes to duplicate, (`src != NULL`), do the following:

   - Allocate a new node, assigning the resulting pointer to `*next`.
   - Copy the node data from `src` to `*next`.
   - Assign `next` to hold the address of the `node->next` member we just allocated. That member is obtainable using `&(*next)->next`.
   - Advance the input source pointer to its next node: `src = src->next`.
   - Repeat to (2).
3. Once finished, always `*next` the value of `NULL`. This ensures the final node added to the list, if any, has `NULL` for it's `next` pointer. If there were no nodes added to the list at all (for example, when `src` is `NULL` when our function is called), this instead sets the value of `dst` to NULL, since it is the address of `dst` currently held in `next`.
4. Return the value of `dst` as the function result.

The code for this algorithm appears below:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node* CopyList(const Node* src)
{
    Node *dst = NULL, **next = &dst;
    while (src)
    {
        // allocate new node
        *next = malloc(sizeof(**next));
        if (*next)
        {
            // copy_node() for complex duplication
            (*next)->data = src->data; 

            // reposition our next-link to the address of ptr->next
            //  of the node we just added.
            next = &(*next)->next;

            // and finally, advance the source pointer
            src = src->next;
        }
        else
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate node.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    *next = NULL;
    return dst;
}
```

Note: This is also a good way to build a forward-linked-list from a serial input file. It ensures the head is only initialized once, and every subsequent node is always tacked on to the last-node's `next` pointer.

Comment: That looks like interesting code! I didn't understand `next = &(*next)->next;` though. Could you please explain what that line is doing?

Comment: @AnishRam Sure. It is a pointer-to-pointer. I.e. it holds the address of a pointer variable. It starts out holding the address of the head pointer we will be returning. When a node is added, it is assigned the address of the `next` pointer of the node that was just added. In other words, it always holds the address of the pointer that will receive the *next* allocated node. At the start, that is `&dst`. After that, its `&(*next)->next`. When finished, we set the pointer it points to to NULL, ensuring the list is NULL-terminated (the last `next` is set to NULL).

Comment: Oh thanks for the explanation! I get it now. But doesn't the OP want a _copy_ of a specified list? In your example, wouldn't each node still be pointing to the original list's next node? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AnishRam No. Each node is allocated, copied from the current node pointed to by `src`, then linked to the last node added to the list (or the head pointer if this is the first node) using the `**next` pointer-to-pointer. The code makes a copy; it does *not* reference anything in the original source list when finished.

Comment: Oh this is really clever! Wish I could up-vote it again.

Comment: @AnishRam Glad you think so. Stepping through it in a debugger is pretty telling on exactly how the algorithm works. Thanks for the up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use recursion at all for this -- simple iteration works perfectly well. Copy a node. If the pointer to the next node isn't null, repeat the process for the next node (and set the `next` link in the node you just copied to point to the next one you copy).

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to copy linked list to an empty list is using recursion as below,

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
};

Node* copy_list(Node* list) {
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;

    Node* result = new Node;
    result->value = list->value;
    result->next = copy_list(list->next);
    return result;
}
```

but in case you dont want to use recursion then you have to manually, copy each not to empty list by using looping untill you get (node)->next = NULL as check.